# How to parse through all the rows with respect to each and every column in the dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing

I have to create columns - column_name, validated_values, predicted_values for each and every row output of my dataframe.

I tried the following code:

```
for file_name in df:
    parsedDF = df[['file_name', 'page_no', 'Name','DOB','Gender','Address','City','State','Zip']]
parsedDF
```

What it looks like right now is:

```
file_name    name    gender    city    state
A           "test"  12          20          30
B           "foo"   18          20          25
```

What I want it to look like is:

```
file_name    column_names    predicted        actual
A           name            X                 X
A           gender          M                 M
A           city            Chicago           Chicago
A           state           IL                IL
B           name            Y                 Y
B           gender          F                 F
B           city            Vegas             Las Vegas
B           state           NV                NV
```

But it doesn't output as desired. The desired output will have duplicates for all the columns.

Can you please help me out here?
Thank you.

Comment: added an answer, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
#duplicate the df into parsedf
parsedf=df.copy() 

#count the number of rows your df (minus 1, since you already have one set of columns
# and using concat, repeat the columns as many time
parsedf = pd.concat([parsedf] * (df['file_name'].count() - 1) )
```

Comment: I am getting the count rightly but I require the values of each column too. The desired output should be like the above tables. I have edited the above, please check.

Comment: where does these actual and predicted values comes from?